# xCode6 hangs when trying to compile to a deployment target smaller than iOS 7

Tags: xcode, xcode6

As soon as I set my deployment target in xCode 6.0.1 to anything smaller than 7 it hangs right at

```
Compiling 14 of 15 XIB files
```

Then the MAC start heating up, the fan runs with highest speed and the xCode processes keep eating memory until the MAC crashes. The only way out is to reboot the machine.

Setting deployment target to 7 runs fine

There seems to be a problem with the asset catalog with deployment targets below I found out.

But why does xCode let me choose iOS 6.1 when it can't compile?

How do I set up xCode 6 to support iOS 6.1 - as someone here says is supported in xCode 6?

I tried to clean, rebuild, change the asset catalog 1000 times - but nothing helps.